# how to design chained operations

Tags: queue

I am working on creating an operations processor which takes a number of entries and performs some operations on them. The operations are chained, I mean the result of one operation will be the input for the next one.

For example:

```
inputs:
5 6 8 
operation +
```

The idea would be to do the operation with the two first digits 5 and 6 and then use the result to do the operation with the third operator, 8 in this case.

To achieve this I'm thinking of using a queue although I am also considering recursive function
Is there a better solution? If not is the use of a queue a good solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with complex Objects, this is almost complete description of [Pipeline_software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software)) and to be more specific [Pipes & filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568100.aspx).